# PHP compare/read images

Tags: php, image

I'm making an application to create and read tests, an user can add questions with the correct answers, I already created a script that outputs the form and a form with answers. Example:

Empty form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFy94.jpg
Form with answers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zezww.jpg

That works perfect, now I printed the empty form, checked boxes, scanned it, and I want to compare them with the answer form to see which boxes are correctly checked.

Scanned filled in form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/23YUX.jpg

I've been looking around for a bit, but can't find the correct way to do this. I tried reading pixel colors with the function "imagecolorat" but the coordinates of the boxes aren't always the same.

I hope somebody can help me in the right direction, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show your HTML?

Comment: You will need some form of OCR library

Comment: @SmitRaval I haven't coded anything for this function yet, I tried some things but it wasn't what I was looking for. The only things I have yet is to create the form with the "imagecreatefrompng" function and a bunch of "imagettftext" to create the numbers / circles showing on the form

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs exactly what I found easier to code, but in this case my client wants people to fill in the form on paper because they do not have computers for everyone at the same time

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs my client wants multiple people to take the test at the same time, and only on paper, he specifically asked for a program that can compare the scanned form with the answers and check how many answers are good

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs yeah its a scanned document

Comment: @Mark ah ok, removed comments :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need OCR, there are no characters/text to recognise.

You need to make a mask of the correct answers (preferably showing the incorrect answers too in a different colour) and overlay it onto the scanned answer sheet then count what is showing through in the correct and incorrect places.

You also need to think about registration, or alignment, so that you overlay the marking template in the correct place over the scanned answer.